# Set solarized scheme on LXTerminal

Tags: vim, colors, lxde, lxterminal

I installed the [solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) theme for vim but it looks quite ugly.

The [documentation](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/vim-colors-solarized#important-note-for-terminal-users) says, that I should also enable the solarized theme in my terminal, which is the LXTerminal. Therefore I tried to setup my terminal via `~/.Xresources` with [`solarized/xresources`](https://github.com/solarized/xresources) but it has no effect.

How can I setup the solarized color scheme for LXTerminal?

Comment: The adaption of `.XResources` works perfectly for XTerm but not for LXTerminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LXTerminal has no color-palette dialog, nor does it recognize X resources.

However, any "recent" LXTerminal can be setup using escape sequences.  Originally VTE lacked that ability, but at some undocumented point the feature was added.

This page has a script which may be useful for this purpose: [solarized-termcolor-osc4](https://github.com/benley/solarized-termcolor-osc4)

Comment: Thanks. I added the two statements from the link to my `.vimrc` and set the background color of LXTerminal to `#002b36`. Looks good.

Comment: According to git log, OSC 4 support was added to VTE in Jan 2009.

Answer (score 5):

Upstream code of LXTerminal (on [git.lxde.org](https://git.lxde.org/gitweb/?p=lxde/lxterminal.git;a=summary) or [GitHub](https://github.com/lxde/lxterminal)) has Solarized palette built-in. This feature has been added last year, but the newer version hasn't been released for many years.

Source: I am one of the LXDE developers and I need Solarized to use LXTerminal, so actually this feature is actually [dogfooding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food) myself (?).  We are currently being pushed and we are going to release a newer version in a week at the time of writing.

**Update:** LXTerminal 0.3.0 is released. For those who has a rolling release distros (like Arch, Debian Sid) it can be immediately available.
The background color and foreground color of Solarized palette is not correct. If you find it bothering, you can change Background color to `#002b36` and Foreground color to `#839496`. For Solarized Light, use `#fdf6e3` and `#657b83` respectively. This will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: In December 2016 version 0.3.0 was released. Could you provide an example how to setup solarized scheme with the new version, please?

Comment: It is right underneath the Palette drop-down menu in preferences.
Though it would be a little bit more difficult to use Light scheme. (It isn't in preset yet.)